# Android Condition checking if else statements?

Tags: android

some mistake i did in this condition can an help me,i am new to technology?sry to ask this type of questions.

```
if (((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) == 
                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)&& config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            final LinearLayout gridViews = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid_id);
            OnNowGridView view = new OnNowGridView(this);
            gridViews.addView(view);

            }
```

  -

---

10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buddytv.android/com.buddytv.android.ui.MainViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-28 20:26:47.244: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)

Comment: i am getting fatal exception..

Comment: We could help more if you would tell us what you tried to do. and a little more context. and one more thing - please paste the logcat log of the exception.

Comment: if (((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE)&& config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)     try this.

Comment: i have did this for 7 inch tablet,my requirement is i have to load the gridvie win landscape mode with largescreens, and portaritmode with listview...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be doing this on the wrong thread.

Comment: Remove your view calls and just create a log their instead, for example Log.d("Test", "This worked");. Using this will show that it is not the if statement that is crashing but adding the view to your gridview on the wrong thread.